# Convert strings to "0" in php

Tags: php

I have a list of strings and some of them have texts in them. Ultimately I want the strings to be added up. The strings that have texts in them, I want to convert them to "0". So what is the right and easy way to do this?

```
<?php

$str_1 = "4";
$str_2 = "A.I";
$str_3 = "8";
$str_4 = "Sky";
$str_5 = "Sa";

$total = intval ($str_1) + intval ($str_2) + intval ($str_3) + intval ($str_4) + intval ($str_5);

?>
```

Ofc the above code won't work. So how does one automatically convert the str2, str3 and str4 to 0?

Comment: I'd put the values in to an array and apply a custom `array_filter` on them. You can either use regular expressions or functions such as `is_numeric` on the values.

Comment: Just do `$total = (int)$str_1 + (int)$str_2 + (int)$str_3 + (int)$str_4 + (int)$str_5;`

Comment: @shingo but i want it to add up so the result is 12.

Comment: Don't you get 12?

Comment: The result of your code as shown, _is_ 12 - https://3v4l.org/Va4EI So what is the actual question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a function that has a [variable-length argument list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list):

```
<?php

/*

Question Author: Vika
Question Answerer: Jacob Mulquin
Question: Convert strings to "0" in php
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74613261/convert-strings-to-0-in-php
Tags: php

*/

function addIfNumeric(...$strings)
{
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($strings as $string) {
        if (is_numeric($string))
            $sum += $string;
    }
    return $sum;
}

$str_1 = "4";
$str_2 = "A.I";
$str_3 = "8";
$str_4 = "Sky";
$str_5 = "Sa";

$sum = addIfNumeric($str_1, $str_2, $str_3, $str_4, $str_5);

echo $sum . PHP_EOL;
```

Yields

```
12
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was looking for. Btw why are you using PHP_EOL?

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is an inbuilt constant that will return the End of LINE (EOL) character that works for the system it's running on, i.e. `\n` for Linux, `\r\n` for Windows.